# Syntax error on token "(", Type expected after this token

Tags: java

So I've run into some errors during this code, error is down where the keys are so 
 first but of code is where the error is, it's saying Syntax error on token "(" Type expected after this token, before I had string without the <> and then keys was underlined and the error was different... so not sure what to do.

Here is where the syntax error is:

```
for (<String> key : keys) {
        Object out = map.get(key);
        out = saveObject(out, field, cs, path + "." + key, depth);
        subCS.set(key, out);
```

The whole file:

```
package me.kalo121;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.configuration.ConfigurationSection;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public abstract class ConfigObject
{
  protected void onLoad(ConfigurationSection cs)
    throws Exception
  {
    for (Field field : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      String path = field.getName().replaceAll("_", ".");
      if (!doSkip(field))
      {
        if (cs.isSet(path))
          field.set(this, loadObject(field, cs, path));
        else
          cs.set(path, saveObject(field.get(this), field, cs, path));
      }
    }
  }

  protected void onSave(ConfigurationSection cs) throws Exception {
    for (Field field : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      String path = field.getName().replaceAll("_", ".");
      if (!doSkip(field))
      {
        cs.set(path, saveObject(field.get(this), field, cs, path));
      }
    }
  }

  protected Object loadObject(Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path) throws Exception {
    return loadObject(field, cs, path, 0);
  }

  protected Object saveObject(Object obj, Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path) throws Exception {
    return saveObject(obj, field, cs, path, 0);
  }

  protected Object loadObject(Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path, int depth) throws Exception
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class clazz = getClassAtDepth(field.getGenericType(), depth);
    if ((ConfigObject.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isConfigurationSection(cs.get(path))))
      return getConfigObject(clazz, cs.getConfigurationSection(path));
    if ((Location.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isJSON(cs.get(path))))
      return getLocation((String)cs.get(path));
    if ((Vector.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isJSON(cs.get(path))))
      return getVector((String)cs.get(path));
    if ((Map.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isConfigurationSection(cs.get(path))))
      return getMap(field, cs.getConfigurationSection(path), path, depth);
    if ((clazz.isEnum()) && (isString(cs.get(path))))
      return getEnum(clazz, (String)cs.get(path));
    if ((List.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isConfigurationSection(cs.get(path)))) {
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class subClazz = getClassAtDepth(field.getGenericType(), depth + 1);
      if ((ConfigObject.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || (Location.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || (Vector.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || 
        (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || (List.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || (subClazz.isEnum())) {
        return getList(field, cs.getConfigurationSection(path), path, depth);
      }
      return cs.get(path);
    }

    return cs.get(path);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected Object saveObject(Object obj, Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path, int depth)
    throws Exception
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class clazz = getClassAtDepth(field.getGenericType(), depth);
    if ((ConfigObject.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isConfigObject(obj)))
      return getConfigObject((ConfigObject)obj, path, cs);
    if ((Location.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isLocation(obj)))
      return getLocation((Location)obj);
    if ((Vector.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isVector(obj)))
      return getVector((Vector)obj);
    if ((Map.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isMap(obj)))
      return getMap((Map)obj, field, cs, path, depth);
    if ((clazz.isEnum()) && (isEnum(clazz, obj)))
      return getEnum((Enum)obj);
    if ((List.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) && (isList(obj))) {
      Class subClazz = getClassAtDepth(field.getGenericType(), depth + 1);
      if ((ConfigObject.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || (Location.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || (Vector.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || 
        (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || (List.class.isAssignableFrom(subClazz)) || (subClazz.isEnum())) {
        return getList((List)obj, field, cs, path, depth);
      }
      return obj;
    }

    return obj;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected Class getClassAtDepth(Type type, int depth)
    throws Exception
  {
    if (depth <= 0) {
      String className = type.toString();
      if ((className.length() >= 6) && (className.substring(0, 6).equalsIgnoreCase("class "))) {
        className = className.substring(6);
      }
      if (className.indexOf("<") >= 0)
        className = className.substring(0, className.indexOf("<"));
      try
      {
        return Class.forName(className);
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("byte")) return Byte.class;
        if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("short")) return Short.class;
        if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("int")) return Integer.class;
        if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("long")) return Long.class;
        if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("float")) return Float.class;
        if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("double")) return Double.class;
        if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("char")) return Character.class;
        if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("boolean")) return Boolean.class;
        throw ex;
      }
    }
    depth--;
    ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType)type;
    Type[] typeArgs = pType.getActualTypeArguments();
    return getClassAtDepth(typeArgs[(typeArgs.length - 1)], depth);
  }

  protected boolean isString(Object obj) {
    if ((obj instanceof String)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  protected boolean isConfigurationSection(Object o) {
    try {
      return (ConfigurationSection)o != null; } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
  }

  protected boolean isJSON(Object obj)
  {
    try {
      if ((obj instanceof String)) {
        String str = (String)obj;
        if (str.startsWith("{")) {
          return new JSONParser().parse(str) != null;
        }
      }
      return false; } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
  }

  protected boolean isConfigObject(Object obj)
  {
    try {
      return (ConfigObject)obj != null; } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
  }

  protected boolean isLocation(Object obj)
  {
    try {
      return (Location)obj != null; } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
  }

  protected boolean isVector(Object obj)
  {
    try {
      return (Vector)obj != null; } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected boolean isMap(Object obj)
  {
    try
    {
      return (Map)obj != null; } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected boolean isList(Object obj)
  {
    try
    {
      return (List)obj != null; } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
  }

  protected boolean isEnum(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz, Object obj)
  {
    if (!clazz.isEnum()) return false;
    for (Object constant : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
      if (constant.equals(obj)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  protected ConfigObject getConfigObject(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz, ConfigurationSection cs)
    throws Exception
  {
    ConfigObject obj = (ConfigObject)clazz.newInstance();
    obj.onLoad(cs);
    return obj;
  }

  protected Location getLocation(String json) throws Exception {
    JSONObject data = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(json);

    World world = Bukkit.getWorld((String)data.get("world"));

    double x = Double.parseDouble((String)data.get("x"));
    double y = Double.parseDouble((String)data.get("y"));
    double z = Double.parseDouble((String)data.get("z"));

    float pitch = Float.parseFloat((String)data.get("pitch"));
    float yaw = Float.parseFloat((String)data.get("yaw"));

    Location loc = new Location(world, x, y, z);
    loc.setPitch(pitch);
    loc.setYaw(yaw);
    return loc;
  }

  protected Vector getVector(String json) throws Exception {
    JSONObject data = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(json);

    double x = Double.parseDouble((String)data.get("x"));
    double y = Double.parseDouble((String)data.get("y"));
    double z = Double.parseDouble((String)data.get("z"));

    return new Vector(x, y, z);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
protected Map getMap(Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path, int depth) throws Exception
  {
    depth++;
    Set keys = cs.getKeys(false);
    Map map = new HashMap();
    if ((keys != null) && (keys.size() > 0)) {
      for (<String> key : keys) {
        Object in = cs.get(key);
        in = loadObject(field, cs, key, depth);
        map.put(key, in);
      }
    }
    return map;
  }

  protected List<String> getList(Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path, int depth) throws Exception
  {
    depth++;
    int listSize = cs.getKeys(false).size();
    String key = path;
    if (key.lastIndexOf(".") >= 0) {
      key = key.substring(key.lastIndexOf("."));
    }
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (listSize > 0) {
      int loaded = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while (loaded < listSize) {
        if (cs.isSet(key + i)) {
          Object in = cs.get(key + i);
          in = loadObject(field, cs, key + i, depth);
          list.add((String) in);
          loaded++;
        }
        i++;

        if (i > listSize * 3) loaded = listSize;
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected Enum getEnum(Class clazz, String string) throws Exception
  {
    if (!clazz.isEnum()) throw new Exception("Class " + clazz.getName() + " is not an enum.");
    for (Object constant : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
      if (((Enum)constant).toString().equals(string)) {
        return (Enum)constant;
      }
    }
    throw new Exception("String " + string + " not a valid enum constant for " + clazz.getName());
  }

  protected ConfigurationSection getConfigObject(ConfigObject obj, String path, ConfigurationSection cs)
    throws Exception
  {
    ConfigurationSection subCS = cs.createSection(path);
    obj.onSave(subCS);
    return subCS;
  }

  protected String getLocation(Location loc) {
    String ret = "{";
    ret = ret + "\"world\":\"" + loc.getWorld().getName() + "\"";
    ret = ret + ",\"x\":\"" + loc.getX() + "\"";
    ret = ret + ",\"y\":\"" + loc.getY() + "\"";
    ret = ret + ",\"z\":\"" + loc.getZ() + "\"";
    ret = ret + ",\"pitch\":\"" + loc.getPitch() + "\"";
    ret = ret + ",\"yaw\":\"" + loc.getYaw() + "\"";
    ret = ret + "}";
    if (!isJSON(ret)) return getLocationJSON(loc); try
    {
      getLocation(ret);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return getLocationJSON(loc);
    }
    return ret;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected String getLocationJSON(Location loc)
  {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    data.put("world", loc.getWorld().getName());

    data.put("x", String.valueOf(loc.getX()));
    data.put("y", String.valueOf(loc.getY()));
    data.put("z", String.valueOf(loc.getZ()));

    data.put("pitch", String.valueOf(loc.getPitch()));
    data.put("yaw", String.valueOf(loc.getYaw()));
    return data.toJSONString();
  }

  protected String getVector(Vector vec) {
    String ret = "{";
    ret = ret + "\"x\":\"" + vec.getX() + "\"";
    ret = ret + ",\"y\":\"" + vec.getY() + "\"";
    ret = ret + ",\"z\":\"" + vec.getZ() + "\"";
    ret = ret + "}";
    if (!isJSON(ret)) return getVectorJSON(vec); try
    {
      getVector(ret);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return getVectorJSON(vec);
    }
    return ret;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected String getVectorJSON(Vector vec)
  {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    data.put("x", String.valueOf(vec.getX()));
    data.put("y", String.valueOf(vec.getY()));
    data.put("z", String.valueOf(vec.getZ()));
    return data.toJSONString();
  }

  protected ConfigurationSection getMap(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map map, Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path, int depth) throws Exception
  {
    depth++;
    ConfigurationSection subCS = cs.createSection(path);
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Set keys = map.keySet();
    if ((keys != null) && (keys.size() > 0)) {
      for (<String> key : keys) {
        Object out = map.get(key);
        out = saveObject(out, field, cs, path + "." + key, depth);
        subCS.set(key, out);
      }
    }
    return subCS;
  }

  protected ConfigurationSection getList(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List list, Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path, int depth) throws Exception
  {
    depth++;
    ConfigurationSection subCS = cs.createSection(path);
    String key = path;
    if (key.lastIndexOf(".") >= 0) {
      key = key.substring(key.lastIndexOf("."));
    }
    if ((list != null) && (list.size() > 0)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Object out = list.get(i);
        out = saveObject(out, field, cs, path + "." + key + (i + 1), depth);
        subCS.set(key + (i + 1), out);
      }
    }
    return subCS;
  }

  protected String getEnum(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Enum enumObj)
  {
    return enumObj.toString();
  }

  protected boolean doSkip(Field field)
  {
    return (Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers())) || (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) || (Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) || 
      (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Syntax errors are off topic here. Use your IDE and find the problem.

Comment: You post a wall of code and it's hard to identify where the issue is located.

Comment: Simple just asking for help sorry, was just hoping 1 person would give me something that's all

Comment: Remove the `<>` around `String`. Do you really have that `for` loop at the top of your source file, before the `package` statement and outside a method? That is not valid Java.

Comment: Horrible code.... Before imports you started to write code ?????? Greatttt

Comment: No that isn't above the package that's just where the error was and I added it on through the website.... and so I get rid of the <> around string and now I get an underlined keys and the error is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String" @Jesper

Comment: That's because the keys in your map are of type `Object`, not `String`. You're using raw types like `Map`, and you're suppressing warnings about raw types. It looks like you're dealing with a whole lot of complicated code that's way over your head. Learn some [Java basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) first.

Comment: I know I have a lot of learning to do, but I just really need this to work so how would I make it work? @Jesper

Comment: @Noongrboy the best way to make it work is to *learn how* to make it work. Jesper gave you hints about what you're doing wrong. Try searching those things and dealing with them one by one. Then, if you still have errors, search for those answers one by one. Asking us to get the code to work for you is not going to help.

Answer (score 2):

`for (<String> key : keys) {` is invalid syntax. The reason `for (String key : keys) {` didn't work either is that the type of your `keys` variable is the raw `Set`, which means you can only iterate over it with `for (Object key : keys) {`.

If you change `Set keys = cs.getKeys(false);` to
`Set<String> keys = cs.getKeys(false);` (assuming this `Set` contains only `String`s), the following with work :

```
for (String key : keys) {
```

Comment: Thanks a ton dude that bit worked but there was also an error at this keys bit aswell and just wondering what the fix for this one was?

Comment: protected ConfigurationSection getMap(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map map, Field field, ConfigurationSection cs, String path, int depth) throws Exception
  {
    depth++;
    ConfigurationSection subCS = cs.createSection(path);
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 Set keys = map.keySet();
    if ((keys != null) && (keys.size() > 0)) {
      for (String key : keys) {
        Object out = map.get(key);
        out = saveObject(out, field, cs, path + "." + key, depth);
        subCS.set(key, out);

Comment: I don't know how to use this website one bit lol so Idk how to do that code easier for you but if you check the main code and go to 4th "protected" tag  from the bottom its there @Eran